# Paths in Dynamic Page Replacing Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For dynamic page changes without having to reload the whole content, I have found this very simple working solution:

**Tutorial**: http://css-tricks.com/rethinking-dynamic-page-replacing-content/

**Demo**: sudojesse.github.io/dynamic-page/

However, this solution only works if you're linking to something like "sitename.html". Is it possible to do the same with folder paths?

**Example:**

**Like it is above:** 
[sudojesse.github.io/dynamic-page/about.html][1]

**Like I want it:** 
[sudojesse.github.io/dynamic-page/more/about/][2]

I have tried it but it doesn't really work!

1. http://sudojesse.github.io/dynamic-page/about.html
2. http://sudojesse.github.io/dynamic-page/more/about/

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work, you would have to rename the file to "index".

The reason for this is because the Web server looks after a specific resource when the client requests a directory. This resource is often by default set to "index"(dot)"something".

Comment: I'm aware of that, thanks though. However it still doesn't work with this specific code when it comes to those dynamic pages. I would love to use this method, but I do not want to show "about.html" in my link bar. I'd rather have /about/ in it. Changing links messes up the javascript and it fails.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to accomplish: If you want a clean URL you can try to fiddle with mod_rewrite. If you want to load parts of the page without having to load the whole thing again you can try XMLHttpRequest. (Comment system is weird.. i deleted and rewrote comment.) :-)